# Filtering pandas dataframe based on attribute of object in a column

Tags: python, pandas

This is something that I can do with a roundabout measure, but I'm wondering if there's something offered by Pandas that makes this possible which might be missing.

So I have a column, "objects", which contains objects that have attributes. One of those attributes is something called "key". I'm trying to filter my dataframe to only include objects whose key belongs in a certain list:

```
df2 = df[df["object"].key.isin(list_of_keys)]
```

The error this returns is
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'key'`

I tried something like this too, but it didn't work:

```
df2 = df[df["object"].map(lambda x: x.key).isin(list_of_keys)]
```

This returns an even more inscrutable error:
`TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: What is the type of `key` attribute?

Comment: It's an S3 bucket object.

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing directly within the lambda function:

```
df2 = df[df["object"].map(lambda x: x.key in list_of_keys)]
```

Comment: This would require me to forego use of the pandas `isin()` method, which is much faster than the python approach you suggest! Thanks though!!